# How to set dropdown width in handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I am trying to set width of handsontable dropdown to be according to the lookup data width, not column width. How can this be achieved?

See picture below please. Dropdown is too narrow to fit lookup data.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: this one is tricky. i'm looking for the answer as well since what i do now is not pretty and mainly involves looking at the elements involved and making their min-width larger

Comment: @ZekeDroid is this fix https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2599 somehow related to the issue here, or maybe since february there is a better way to solve the problem above? Thanks

Comment: yup! that's the solution

Comment: so I guess we have to wait for ver. 16 to test this. Then looking forward to it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ZekeDroid, can you put the answer in answer section so I can award you a bounty. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2599

Github has a section on this.

Add the `trimDropdown` property. By default, this property is set to true. If you set it to false, this should accomplish what you need to do.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Apologies. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [Github fix](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2599) on 0.16 will include this solution. It's actually really nice, I'm using it already.

Comment: While 0.16 is supposed to offer a solution, the solution is not working. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2599) and looking forward for a fix.

Comment: I confirmed today they are still working on the issue so that is good.  I just thought people on here would want to know.  I've been patiently waiting. [HERE](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2599#issuecomment-134619917) is the updated issue conversation.

Comment: There has been update that this will be fixed on the next release of HandsOnTable.  Check link in previous comment.